# Is there a way to programmaticaly upload a whole skill to DialogFlow?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant-sdk, api-ai, dialogflow-es

I want to generate the whole action JSONs in code, and then upload them, instead of working through the console.
There is an option to download the whole package as a zipped JSON and theoretically you can also upload. That might supply a hint on how to create the JSONs.

However, these files have all kinds of IDs for the different building blocks, such as Intents or Entity. So, when I export from DialogFlow, of course I get IDs for these.

But, if I want to create a new google action, do I generate these action IDs myself? 
Is there documentation on what the structure of these JSONs should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format used by the export/import process is not documented, and while you can try to work with it, there is no guarantee that it will continue to work in the future.

Depending on your needs, it may be better to work with the [Dialogflow API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/) (the former API of API.ai). This provides an API to build and modify Intents and Entities (and do some other things). It isn't clear, however, that this provides access to the settings for various integrations.